# React Hooks Import

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks

I have two components useSimpleCard.js and Header.js.
How can I use the SimpleCard hook in the Header.js?

SimpleCard.js:

```
export default function SimpleCard() {
const classes = useStyles();
const icon = <img alt='logo' src={logo} />;
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);

<Button size="small" color="secondary" variant='contained' onClick={() => { setCount(count + 1); }}>In den Warenkorb</Button>

<Badge color="secondary" badgeContent={count}>
 {icon}
</Badge>
```

Header.js:

```
import SimpleCard from './Card';

export default function Header() {
const classes = useStyles();

const [count, setCount] = React.useState(SimpleCard);

const icon = <img alt='logo' className={classes.size} src={logo} />;

return (
<div className={classes.root}>
  <AppBar position="static" className={classes.color}>
    <Toolbar>
      <Drawer />
       <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
        E-Commerce App
       </Typography>
       <Badge color="secondary" badgeContent={count}>
        {icon}
      </Badge>
```

Comment: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Answer (score 0):

You can’t get the state from another component this way.

If SimpleCard is a child of Header, then SimpleCard should accept `count` as a prop. Header will have `count` as its own state and pass the current value to SimpleCard as a prop. This concept is called [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and is important to be familiar with when using React.